# How to back up current config?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, source-engine

I want to save my current cfg. I did this once which writes a cfg in cfg folder. But couldnt remember what command was.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write your configuration file to disk using the following command in the CS:GO console;

`host_writeconfig <name_of_file>`

For example, if you wanted to write your current configuration settings to a file called "myConfig.cfg",  you would use the following in the CS:GO console;

`host_writeconfig myConfig`

This would create a file called `myConfig.cfg` containing all of your current configuration settings in the `Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg` folder within your Steam folder or Steam library folder.

Using `host_writeconfig` without any parameters will save all of your current configuration settings into the config.cfg file.